# If I buy a DLC for SSB Ultimate that my child has bought on my Switch will it mess anything up?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate, nintendo-eshop, nintendo-account

My brother has a child account on his Switch Lite that is connected to my account on my Switch Lite, and that account is considered to be a parent account. He bought a Super Smash Bros Ultimate DLC that I want to buy.

I am able to buy it, but I’m concerned that if I buy it, it will mess something up.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not, the character(s) you bought will just be added to the roster in all accounts, no need to battle them first.

Comment: Hi Roxy, the question doesn't seem to be asking about battling them, rather if buying the DLC again will mess anything up.

Comment: I think this answer is fine. In addition to simply answering the yes/no question of messing something up, it helpfully describes how the DLC affects the multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This will not break or mess up anything. Your accounts are still separate, even though they are parent/child accounts.